# SQL splitting a column and updating alternate table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working with a few different tables consisting of data from users rating movies. My movies table currently lists MovieId, MovieTitle, and Category. The data in each category column has repeating groups in each row that I want to eliminate by moving them over to MovieCategories which will consist of MovieId, CategoryId.

My category column uses | as a delimiter, such as "Action | Thriller | Drama". I have a separate table CategoryDescription that assigns a CategoryId to each genre, so for example, I want my final MovieCategories table to look like this:

```
 MovieId | CategoryId
------------------------
 1           1
 1           4
 1           7
```

and so on for each movie and their respective genres. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Okay so  - desired result would be the table I have above, listing each movie and each individual genre. So for example, lets say in my movies table I have:

```
MovieId   |   MovieTitle    | Category
  1            Toy Story        Animated | Childrens
  2            Die Hard         Action | Thriller
```

I would want my MovieCategories table to have the MovieId and the corresponding CategoryId from my Categories table (which lists CategoryId 1-20 and each respective genre), so my result in my final table with the data above would be

```
 MovieId     |   CategoryId
 1                  1
 1                  4
 2                  3
 2                  5
```

Hope that makes sense!

One more edit:

Thanks for the comments so far guys. I was able to get a query to produce almost the results I want, but how do I update my MovieCategories table now? Here's the query that worked:

```
 select distinct
    DUMMYMOVIES.MovieId,
    trim(regexp_substr(DUMMYMOVIES.CatDescription, '[^|]+', 1, 
   levels.column_value)) as Category
  from 
    DUMMYMOVIES,
    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= 
   length (regexp_replace(DUMMYMOVIES.CatDescription, '[^|]+'))  + 1) as 
   sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
  order by MovieId;
```

This split the Category column correctly, but how do I get this over to my MovieCategories table? Can I use an UPDATE statement and have it run this query, checking the category name against my CategoryDescription table?

Comment: What SQL are you using MSSQL?  If you are using 2016 there is a built in split function.

Comment: Oh sorry - should've specified. I'm using oracle SQL developer.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I edited my post with some additional info.

Comment: Its getting little bit out of hand - we are drifting from original question, and expanding it (bad practice).I suggest one problem - one question(if needed). Don't stack more questions in same post.

Answer (score 0):

i created 2 dummy table movies and category. populate sample data and desired output.

Movie table creation:

```
create table movie
(
movie_id varchar2(200),
movie_title varchar2(100),
category varchar2(100)
);

insert into movie values (1,'Toy Story','Animated | Childrens');
insert into movie values (2,'Die Hard','Action | Thriller');
```

Category table creation:

```
create table category
(
categoryid varchar2(100),
categoryname varchar2(100)
);


insert into category values (1,'Animated');
insert into category values (4,'Childrens');
insert into category values (3,'Action');
insert into category values (5,'Thriller');
```

Main query:

```
select t1.movie_id,t2.CATEGORYID from
(
select distinct cat,movie_id from(
select trim(regexp_substr(category, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)) as cat,movie_id from movie  
CONNECT BY instr(category, '|', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0)) t1
join
CATEGORY t2 on t1.cat = t2.categoryname;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Tried to improvise (with screaming kids in the background) - came up with solution (could need some tweaks, but could be a good start):

```
with tmp_tbl as(
  select
    1 MovieId,
    'Toy Story' MovieTitle,
    'Animated | Childrens' Category
  from dual
  union all
  select
    2 MovieId,
    'Die Hard' MovieTitle,
    'Action | Thrille' Category
  from dual
  union all
  select
    3 MovieId,
    'Beuty and the Beast' MovieTitle,
    'Musical | Comedy | Kids' Category
  from dual)
select
  tmp_out.movieid,
  tmp_out.MovieTitle,
  trim(tmp_out.category_splited)
from(
  select
    tmp.movieid,
    tmp.MovieTitle,
    regexp_substr(tmp.Category,'[^|]+', 1, level) category_splited
  from
    tmp_tbl tmp
  connect by
    regexp_substr(tmp.Category,'[^|]+', 1, level) is not null) tmp_out
group by
  tmp_out.movieid,
  tmp_out.MovieTitle,
  tmp_out.category_splited
order by
  tmp_out.movieid,
  tmp_out.category_splited
```

The output:

```
1   Toy Story             Animated
1   Toy Story             Childrens
2   Die Hard              Action
2   Die Hard              Thrille
3   Beuty and the Beast   Musical
3   Beuty and the Beast   Kids
3   Beuty and the Beast   Comedy
```